# How to stay subscribed *while* certain types of events are emitted?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, rx-java2

I have one I cannot figure out

basically I have stream of polymorphic events, and want to subscribe a observable "while" in a given state, i.e. previous emit was event of same type, then keep the subscribtion and just proxy the event

```
Events = (A|B)
stream: A1 A2 B1 B2 B3 A3 A4 A5 B4 B5 B6
              ^------^          ^------^
              subscribed        subscribed
```

problem is how to attach the observable without resubscribing it
i.e.

```
events.switchMap {
   if(it is B) {
      somethingIWant()
   } else {
      Observable.empty()
   }
}
```

which will obviously keep resubscribing somethingIwant in case of B1, B2, ...

I need it to stay subscribed during Bs, and if something else than B comes, unsubscribe

`events.ofType(B)` wont also work because it wont unsubscribe downstream in case A comes
basically I want a conditional switchmap, with option to emit via already subscribed stream, whch Im not sure possible

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs provides pipeable operator that emits only those value that is required.

Here In the Below`events.pipe(filter => 'if it is B')`

It will not emit the A events.

```js
console.clear()
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>RXJS Filter - fromEvent -fire -click or dblClick Event</h1>`;
const { fromEvent,merge } = rxjs;
const { map, filter }= rxjs.operators;
// common function to display event
const dipslayEvent = (event2,message) => {
   console.log(message, ' ', event2.type);
   appDiv.innerHTML += '<h5> '+ message + ' '+ event2.type +' <h5>'
}
//create observable that emits dblclick events
const source = fromEvent(document, 'dblclick');
//create observable that emits click events
const source1 = fromEvent(document, 'click');
// mergring the observales   
const event = merge(source,source1);
event.subscribe(event1 => dipslayEvent(event1,'event fired'))
//filterout the event that are requied
const example = event.pipe(filter(event => event.type === 'dblclick'));
// only subsacribed to those event that are required
const subscribe = example.subscribe(event1 => dipslayEvent(event1,'event as per required'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Here the [stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-filter-fromevent)

Comment: Sorry filtering wont help, I need a new subscription; unless im missing something

Comment: I am not able to replicate the exact requirement.can you please givevexample